# JSON data POST to Web API works in Fiddler but “Bad Request” error from JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I am calling Web API from jQuery AJAX. (Which I run my ajax from my local machine and calling Web API from ANOTHER SERVER).

http://10.10.22.33:777/api/student/DelStudentDetail?stuID=1

It is working if manually call using fiddler.(Response = 200)

But If I call using jQuery AJAX, and fiddler will capture 400 Bad request (error = {"Message":"The origin http://localhost:49983" is not allowed."}) 
(If is working if i change the 10.10.22.33 ip to localhost)

Here is the jQuery code:

```js
return $.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (res) {
                MobileAppsPOCDevExtreme.app.navigate(navigateview);
                DevExpress.ui.notify({
                    message: "modified Successfully!"
                }, "success");
            },
            error: function (res) {
                DevExpress.ui.notify({
                    message: "modification Failed!"
                }, "error");
            }
        });
```

I tried to deploy my Web API to my local machine and it is WORKING FINE. Please help.

Comment: Maybe this is a [CORS](http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/) problem?

Comment: @JeroenHeier usually it is

Comment: @JeroenHeier My fiddler response show: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: But i try to manually trigger from fiddler, it is working.

Comment: Just notice if calling cross server API, the request header become "OPTIONS /api/student/PostStudentDetailStdWay HTTP/1.1" but if call localhost API, the request header is "POST /api/student/PostStudentDetailStdWay HTTP/1.1". Any idea?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) Mozilla page.